# R 3.0 lookbehind will not work

Tags: regex, r, regex-lookarounds, lookbehind

I am trying to capture text from medical reports using regex with a lookahead/lookbehind.

lookahead works fine, lookbehind will not work at all:

```
library(plyr)
library(tm)
library(stringr)
library(gsubfn)

d1 <- c("CCA: 135 cm/sec ICA:", "CCA: 150 cm/sec ICA:")
d1
[1] "CCA: 135 cm/sec ICA:" "CCA: 150 cm/sec ICA:"

# Lookahead works
d1$sub1 <- lapply((strapply(d1,".*?(?=ICA:)")), unique)
Warning message:
In d1$sub1 <- lapply((strapply(d1, ".*?(?=ICA:)")), unique) :
Coercing LHS to a list
d1
[[1]]
[1] "CCA: 135 cm/sec ICA:"

[[2]]
[1] "CCA: 150 cm/sec ICA:"

$sub1
$sub1[[1]]
[1] "CCA: 135 cm/sec " ""                

$sub1[[2]]
[1] "CCA: 150 cm/sec " ""                

# lookbehind fails
d1$sub2 <- lapply((strapply(d1,"(?<=CCA:).*?(?=ICA:)")), unique)
```

The error:

```
Error in structure(.External("dotTcl", ..., PACKAGE = "tcltk"), class = "tclObj") : 
[tcl] couldn't compile regular expression pattern: quantifier operand invalid.
```

I know there is an error message about using lapply - but since lookahead works it seems that lookbehind should as well.

Maybe I am using lookbehind incorrectly, but all the examples I can find this is the syntax.  Any help?

Answer (score 3):

Found the problem:

perl = TRUE fixed the issue.

Comment: I'm pretty sure this is the same result in R2.15, etc